# Как открыть файл с расширением .doc из ListBox?

Tags: c#, doc

Доброго времени суток! 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как открыть файл с расширением `.doc` из `ListBox` в C#?

Вот Мой код

```
private void text1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog fd = new OpenFileDialog();
    fd.Title = "Файл";
    fd.Filter = "docx (*.*)|*.*|docx (*.*)|*.*";
    fd.Title = "Открыть документ";
    Process.Start("..\\..\\Документы\\.1234.docx");
    if (fd.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
    {              
        string fileName = fd.FileName;
        FileStream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    }
}
```

Comment: А что вы, как программист, подразумеваете под словом "открыть"?

Comment: вы бы еще файл формата dll попробовали "из ListBox" открыть

Comment: Я не программист. Изучаю язык C# совсем не давно и много не знаю. Подразумеваю под словом открыть запустить файл в Word.

Comment: Тогда воспользуйтесь просто `Process.Start`, передав имя файла как аргумент. `File.Open` — совершенно другое понятие, названия одинаковы лишь по случайному совпадению.